# Route returning 404 regardless the resource being requested - Laravel/Inertis.js - caused by route ordering

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, inertiajs

I have this route in `web.php`

```
Route::get('crm/projects/add', [CRMController::class, 'addProject'])->name('crm.addProject')->middleware('auth');
```

this is in the `CRMController` class

```
public function addProject(){
    return Inertia::render('CRM/Projects/AddProjectPage');
}
```

Regardless of the resource I tell the function to render it returns a 404

I am positive that the resource exists at `CRM/Projects/AddProjectPage` and I have tried with other resources which also have working links in the site so they are certainly there and it returns me a 404 anyways

the route is being referenced like this in a Vue component

```
<inertia-link :href="route('crm.addProject')">
    Add Project
</inertia-link>
```

I must be missing something plainly obvious, an extra set of eyes would help, thank you in advance

EDIT:
the error in the console is

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) projects/add:1
```

EDIT:
output of `php artisan route:list`

```
|        | GET|HEAD | crm/projects/add                                      | crm.addProject        | App\Http\Controllers\CRMController@addProject               | web
```

Comment: php artisan route:list
use this command to get all routes list

Comment: @Shailendra added relevant output to question

Comment: <inertia-link :href="route('crm.addProject')"> did you check what is href value here and is other auth get routes working well or only this route gives error

Comment: @Shailendra it renders to `<a href="https://www.britevisual.com/crm/projects/add">Add Project</a>` and yes all other `auth` routes work correctly including a route/resource process for adding a different model somewhere else which this one is a copy of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, which couldn't have been solved due to inadequate info provided on my behalf, was route ordering

this route

```
Route::get('crm/projects/{project:id}', [CRMController::class, 'editProjectPage'])->name('crm.project')->middleware('auth');
```

was declared before

```
Route::get('crm/projects/add', [CRMController::class, 'addProject'])->name('crm.addProject')->middleware('auth');
```

so due to route resolution being an ordered thing, it caused me issues, i would say for best practice have all routes which are checking for passed params **after** your other routes not accepting params

like so

```
Route::get('crm/projects/add', [CRMController::class, 'addProject'])->name('crm.addProject')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('crm/projects/{project:id}', [CRMController::class, 'editProjectPage'])->name('crm.project')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Ah yes, this happened to me before, to eliminate this kind of problem, I suggest to use [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups), happy coding :)

Comment: @JasonMigz I appreciate your help, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an obvious thing but have you tried running

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

And make sure you have `npm run watch` running while you are working with Inertia and Laravel.

Comment: These commands didn't resolve my issue thanks for the attempt

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/npm-clear-cache Maybe this will help? The only reason i think its more of a npm problem than a logic problem is because your controller/route/recourse all look correctly setup to me.

Comment: clearing the cache didn't resolve it either, the controller/route/resource process _is_ set up properly because it's a copy of an existing process for adding another model instance in the CRM, this is very odd behaviour, i appreciate your help if you have more thoughts please share

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/404-not-found-but-route-exists

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run `php artisan` command below to generate routes using Ziggy

```
php artisan ziggy:generate
```

It will store your generated routes here

```
resources/js/ziggy.js
```

Reference: https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

Comment: Thanks but the issue is not the route, it is the failure to find the resource, or any resource for that matter, in the location it is told to look

Comment: @LiamO'Toole did you already check your `resources/js/ziggy.js` if your route is there?

Comment: Ziggy is declared as a directive in the base html for the vue app because that's how Inertia has it working, there is no `resources/js/ziggy.js` and I am confident it will not solve the problem, again thank you for the attempt

Comment: did you add the `@routes` Blade directive to your main layout (before your application's JavaScript) ?

Comment: yes, that's what i was referring to in the last comment, this is a big site with lots of other parts working in similar ways to this this is just an instance where something is wrong and i cannot see what it is

Comment: @LiamO'Toole in you `web.php` are you using route groups? as i saw you comments above, the `:href="route('crm.addProject')"` is generated a link, how that link is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235392/discussion-between-jason-migz-and-liam-otoole).